# Unable to use Chinese Remainder Theorem on a question.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

So I had recently learned about Chinese Remainder theorem, and I got a Question to solve:
Find X if-
$X\equiv 1\bmod 2\\X\equiv 2 \bmod 3\\X\equiv 3 \bmod 4\tag*{}$
So I went on to find the solution modulus, $N=24$ & $N_1=12\\ N_2 = 8\\ N_3 = 6\tag*{}$
And now I just had to find the three inverse modulus, but for the first one
$12y_1\equiv 1 \bmod 2\tag*{}$ there's no $y_1$ satisfying the equation. I was stuck on this part. Please Highlight what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you explain how your steps work? I don't get what you're doing.

Comment: Hint: $\ X\equiv -1\,$ for all moduli.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CRT doesn't apply right away because your moduli are not relatively prime.  So there my not be a solution.  If the last congruence had been $x\equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ then this would contradict the first congruence.

So in cases like this, one has to be observant and note that any solution to $x \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ also satisfies $x\equiv 1 \pmod{2}$.  So your first congruence is superfluous, and you can delete it.   In more complicated cases, you can proceed in gimusi's answer.  If you hit a contradiction doing that, then there is no solution.

Answer (score 4):

Note that CRT guarantees that a unique solution $\bmod {12}$ exists but doesn't give any particular method to solve the system other than those used for the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Case_of_two_moduli).

Indeed note that for the given system the third equation is equivalent to the first (in the sense that the third implies the first one butnot viceversa)

- $X\equiv 1\bmod 2$
- $X\equiv 2 \bmod 3$
- $X\equiv 3 \bmod 4\implies X\equiv 3 \bmod {2^2}$

thus we can study the following reduced system

- $X\equiv 2 \bmod 3$
- $X\equiv 3 \bmod 4$

and find that 
$$X\equiv -1 \equiv 11\bmod {12}$$

Notably

- $X\equiv 2 \bmod 3 \implies X=2+3k$
- $X\equiv 3 \bmod 4\implies 2+3k \equiv 3 \bmod 4 \implies -k \equiv 1 \bmod 4 \implies k\equiv -1 \bmod 4 \implies k=-1+4h \implies X=2+3(-1+4h)=-1+12h$

Comment: So, that means the method I was trying to use doesnt work for every case?

Comment: @user178139 You can simplify the system first, I add this way which is indeed more effective and correct!

Comment: The CRT does not guarantee a solution when the moduli are not relatively prime.

Comment: @B.Goddard yes I've indeed indicated the correct modulus but I jumped a step, now it would be clear!

Answer (score 2):

$x \equiv 1 (\mod 2) \Rightarrow x-1$ divisible by $2$ $\Rightarrow x-1+2=x+1$ is divisible by $2$.

$x \equiv 2 (\mod 3) \Rightarrow x-2$ divisible by $3$ $\Rightarrow x-2+3=x+1$ is divisible by $3$.

$x \equiv 3 (\mod 4) \Rightarrow x-3$ divisible by $4$ $\Rightarrow x-3+4=x+1$ is divisible by $4$.

Because $x+1$ is divisible by $2;3;4$, it is also divisible by the least common multiple of them, which is $12$ (but not neccesarily the product of them or $24$, because these numbers are not relatively prime)

We can imply that $x \equiv -1 $(mod $12)$ or $x \equiv 11 $(mod $12)$, which means $x$ can be expressed in the form $x=12k+11$ for non-negative integers $k$.